# Google maps v3 not showing polyline with my set of coordinates. It works with the coordinates provided in the example. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There's something weird going on. I tried to draw a polyline to mark the boundary of a region. I have the coordinates for the boundary. But when I try to draw the polyline, it doesn't get displayed.

To check whether something is wrong, I tried the code given in the Google Maps Doc example. It works for those coordinates. I have included that code also (it is commented).

```
function initialize() 
{
  var bangalore = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9102585,77.6456604);
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom:11,
      center: bangalore,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: true,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
      },
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var boundaryCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.446060, 13.096199),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.378082, 13.130304),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.365723, 13.094861),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.382202, 13.084160),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.378082, 12.981810),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.367783, 12.952368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.384949, 12.942330),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.382202, 12.897489),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.417908, 12.893473),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.391815, 12.820505),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.429581, 12.795732),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.511292, 12.744168),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.579956, 12.739479),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.597122, 12.787696),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.632141, 12.790375),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.632141, 12.835904),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.663727, 12.826531),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.651367, 12.804436),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.680206, 12.798410),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.711792, 12.807114),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.739258, 12.867368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.769470, 12.854649),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.862167, 12.822514),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.883453, 12.832557),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.891693, 12.868037),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.888260, 12.893473),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.859421, 12.926268),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.823029, 12.969096),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.830582, 12.989839),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.789383, 12.988500),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.796249, 13.059413),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.823029, 13.068108),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.818222, 13.083491),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.770844, 13.082154),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.750931, 13.115593),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.761230, 13.150364),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.737885, 13.152370),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.663040, 13.155045),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.587509, 13.167080),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.501678, 13.156382),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.507172, 13.177777),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.467346, 13.177108),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.472153, 13.165074),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.437820, 13.157719),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.427521, 13.137660),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.442627, 13.131642),
      new google.maps.LatLng(77.446060, 13.096199),
  ];

  var boundary = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: boundaryCoordinates,
      geodesic: false,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
  });

  boundary.setMap(map);

  // var flightPlanCoordinates = [
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  // ];

  //   console.log(flightPlanCoordinates);

  // var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  //   path: flightPlanCoordinates,
  //   geodesic: true,
  //   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  //   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  //   strokeWeight: 2
  // });

  // flightPath.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

EDIT: Here's a codepen if you want to try.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOVVmr

Comment: Tried that also. Doesn't work.

Comment: Any error in the console? What browser are you using? Depending on that, maybe try to remove the trailing comma in your arrays.

Comment: Looks like you have the latitude and longitude backwards (77 degrees is pretty far north).  Compare the coordinates in the map center (12.9102585,77.6456604) to the coordinates in your polyline (77.446060, 13.096199). [Your polyline is there, it is just up north of Sweden](http://jsfiddle.net/amcgvsq7/)

Comment: Yes, your polygon works. It's just in the middle of the Greenland sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your coordinates backwards, the first argument to the google.maps.LatLng class should be latitude, the second should be longitude.  You are using it (incorrectly) like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<longitude>,<latitude>);
```

should be

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<latitude>,<longitude>);
```

```js
function initialize() {
  var bangalore = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9102585, 77.6456604);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: bangalore,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var boundaryCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.446060, 13.096199),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.378082, 13.130304),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.365723, 13.094861),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.382202, 13.084160),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.378082, 12.981810),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.367783, 12.952368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.384949, 12.942330),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.382202, 12.897489),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.417908, 12.893473),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.391815, 12.820505),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.429581, 12.795732),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.511292, 12.744168),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.579956, 12.739479),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.597122, 12.787696),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.632141, 12.790375),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.632141, 12.835904),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.663727, 12.826531),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.651367, 12.804436),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.680206, 12.798410),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.711792, 12.807114),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.739258, 12.867368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.769470, 12.854649),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.862167, 12.822514),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.883453, 12.832557),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.891693, 12.868037),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.888260, 12.893473),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.859421, 12.926268),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.823029, 12.969096),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.830582, 12.989839),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.789383, 12.988500),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.796249, 13.059413),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.823029, 13.068108),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.818222, 13.083491),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.770844, 13.082154),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.750931, 13.115593),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.761230, 13.150364),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.737885, 13.152370),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.663040, 13.155045),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.587509, 13.167080),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.501678, 13.156382),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.507172, 13.177777),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.467346, 13.177108),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.472153, 13.165074),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.437820, 13.157719),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.427521, 13.137660),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.442627, 13.131642),
    new google.maps.LatLng(77.446060, 13.096199),
  ];
  var boundaryCoordinatesRev = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < boundaryCoordinates.length; i++) {
    boundaryCoordinatesRev.push(new google.maps.LatLng(boundaryCoordinates[i].lng(), boundaryCoordinates[i].lat()));
  }
  var boundary = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: boundaryCoordinatesRev,
    geodesic: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
  });

  boundary.setMap(map);

  // var flightPlanCoordinates = [
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
  //     new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  // ];

  //   console.log(flightPlanCoordinates);

  // var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  //   path: flightPlanCoordinates,
  //   geodesic: true,
  //   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  //   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  //   strokeWeight: 2
  // });

  // flightPath.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: It works. But why? Should there be any order for the polyline?

Comment: `LatLng` class expects *as its name says* a latitude and a longitude as parameters. You give a longitude and a latitude.